# collisions detection between my player and a block from a 2d-array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a little game just for the fun of it where i have some collision problems.

I have a player drawn on a canvas and some blocks (16 x 16px) drawn on another canvas.

But i have a problem with detecting horizontal collisions.

...

My problem comes down to this:

My player uses x y coordinates that are stored as:

```
var p_x; var p_y;
```

these values is the players bottom left coordinates in pixels.

But my blocks is in a 2d array called:

```
var g_levelarray;
```

And each block is 16 x 16 px so for instance if i do:

```
g_levelarray[3][2] = 1;
```

means that a block will be drawn at canvas left: 48px and canvas bottom 32px

...

But then i have my code to check if block exists (according to  player) where the x and y is playercoordinates

```
function blockexists(x, y) {
    var xpos = parseInt(x / g_blocksize);
    var ypos = parseInt(y / g_blocksize);


    $("#checkedblock").html("checked block: " + xpos + " " + ypos);


    if (g_levelarray[xpos][ypos] != undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but that check has some errors due to the fact that it rounds down the number so when i hit a block from half down the top (as shown on image below) it allows player to go inside block.

[image: the error i have]
<sub>(source: [userhome.org](http://userhome.org/test/error.png))</sub>

i have also tried Math.round instead of parseInt but that just makes a problem at players middle.

So how can i write this code in a right way so that my player doesnt go into the block?

thx in advance

Comment: If `g_levelarray[xpos][ypos]` represents a string then
what goes inside the `indexOf()` method n your code?

Comment: I think i misunderstood you at first but yeah i get your point. Index of code is wrong. It should be indexOf('t') == -1. Lol. But still not the problem though :) but i just removed that for now.

Comment: `return g_levelarray[xpos][ypos] != undefined` would be cleaner.

Comment: One thing I noticed in your code that if `xpos` is not in the array then `g_levelarray[xpos]` will also be undefined, so the `g_levelarray[xpos][ypos]` tries to access an element of an object which itself is undefined. So you can put a check for the existence of the `xpos` element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just using the `parseInt` and `round` try using a range.

Take the lower bound(`Math.floor`) and the upper bound `Math.ceil` and check if the block exists in this range by checking these values in the array.